# how to build first app on Rhomobile

Tags: rhomobile

I have installed Rhostudion and when creating first Rhomobile Project and run as rhomobile app then it works well in Rho simulator. When I run as device on android platform then it shows an error as below:

> rake aborted! Build failed: rhodes
>
> Tasks: TOP => run:android:device => run:android:device:build =>
>   device:android:debug => package:android => build:android:all =>
>   build:android:rhodes => build:android:librhodes

Using RhoStudion Version 5.4.0 ndk version android-ndk-r11c

After running on Rhosimulator as android platform, how can i get the apk?

Comment: Hi, can you clarify your question? What are you trying to accomplish? What is not working? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yup.. I have installed Rhostudion and when creating first Rhomobile Project and run as rhomobile app then it works well in Rho simulator but when i run as device on android platform then it show the error as below.                      
rake aborted! Build failed: rhodes

Tasks: TOP => run:android:device => run:android:device:build => device:android:debug => package:android => build:android:all => build:android:rhodes => build:android:librhodes


RhoStudion Version 5.4.0
ndk version android-ndk-r11c

Comment: After running on Rhosimulator as android platform how can  i get the apk.

Comment: android NDK is mandatory? how to set it. I am stuck here

Answer (score 1):

You can find the guide on how to setup RhoMobile for Android development on the [documentation website](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.4/guide/nativesdksetup).
I'm not sure that NDK r11c is currently supported, just keep in mind that you need to have the Android SDK as well with one Android API SDK installed (minimum Level 10).
For question linked to RhoMobile may be worthwhile to use [Zebra Technologies' Launchpad](https://developer.zebra.com/community/rhomobile-suite) that is the main community for RhoMobile developers.

*Disclaimer: I work for Zebra Technologies.*

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. Its working for android-ndk-r9d and sdk version 4.4.2 api level 22. Thanks pfmaggi..!

Comment: what is ndk path? Where could i found that?

Answer (score 0):

RhoMobile Suite 6.0

Tau releases a BIG update of the RhoMobile suite, version 6.0. It features lots of changes and improvements, most significant of which are support of Node.js environment on mobile devices, HTML5 support on Windows CE and major upgrade of Ruby interpreter.

See more in release notes.
http://rhomobile.tau-technologies.com/6.0/6.0.0/6.0%20Release%20Notes.pdf

Visit the Tau Technologies download page to get latest builds.

Regards,
Tau Technologies